# Is there a way to print qrcode to a pdf in Laravel, without the XML tag?

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-blade

I am using **SimpleSoftwareIO/simple-qrcode** to generate Qr-code, like this;

```
 <div class="card">
     <div class="card-body">
         {!! QrCode::size(300)->generate('hello')!!}
     </div>
</div>
```

And I am using **mccarlosen/laravel-mpdf** for generaating pdf, like this;

```
 $pdf = LaravelMpdf::loadView(
         'testing_qr' ,compact('testing'),
            [],
            ['orientation'=>'landscape','format'=>'A5']);
        return $pdf->stream('test.pdf');
```

But I keep getting a pdf with **XML** tag, like this;

[how the qrcode looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oIyX.png)

If I use this blade file as a normal html page, the xml tag doesn't, but if I used it in a pdf it shows up.

Can someone please show me how to remove the tag and remain with the barcode only.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

I am using:

milon/barcode

mccarlosen/laravel-mpdf

```
{!! str_replace('<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>', '', DNS1D::getBarcodeSVG($barcode, 'C39',3,100)); !!}
```

This helped me.

Comment: I hope I can give you 10 upvotes, this answer is great

Answer (score 0):

One possible way, but **not recommended** is to change your qr's package source files to remove that xml tag.

If you prefer to go this way, you can remove that tag easily from `/vendor/yourqrpackage`.

If you can't find that file, you can easily search for  `'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' . "\n" .` and remove this piece of code.

For example in my case it is: `vendor/werneckbh/qrcode/src/QR_Code/Encoder/Vector.php` file that includes this code. When I removed the `'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' . "\n" .` part, it was generating qr without that string.

Answer (score 0):

I use like this and it works :

```
   $qrcode=QrCode::size(80)->generate('Example of QR code!');
   $code = (string)$qrcode;
   echo substr($code,38);
```

Answer (score -2):

use this package to generate the barcode https://github.com/milon/barcode

Comment: it's the not the point of `milon/barcode` it's because of the `SVG`

Comment: The problem occures also with the Milon package